# MSI GS70 reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media

Tags: boot, system-installation

I just bought an MSI GS70 and I wanted to install Ubuntu from a Live USB. As suggested by other posts, I switched the boot mode to Legacy and after that the only thing that happens when I start up my computer is the message 
"Reboot and select proper boot device or insert boot media" on a black screen. I don't know how to access BIOS or get Windows 8 to boot. Please help me!

Comment: please select the usb option from the boot menu in bios.

Comment: Below link will help you http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the USB boot priority higher than the hard disk. It looks like your machine is still trying to boot from your hard disk but obviously can't do so in Legacy mode.

Press Delete key when powering up your machine, go to the BIOS setting, and changes the boot priority settings. This post (http://gs70-linux.blogspot.com/2013_09_01_archive.html) has more information about how it works.  Ubuntu 13.04 is the easiest version to install on this machine with most hardware working.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 13.04 is outdated, install the 64 bit version of Ubuntu 14.10 or 14.04.2 LTS

The webpage is indeed very good but use any of the versions I have told you:

http://gs70-linux.blogspot.com.es/2013_09_01_archive.html

Download Ubuntu:

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Scroll down for Ubuntu 14.10 and select 64 bits on any of them.

Comment: This is from 2013.

Answer (score 0):

1. Reset the bios from the cmos reset on the mobo (look at your documentation)
2. Switch back to uefi and boot to windows
3. Download rufus and format tour usb pen to gpt / fat32
4. Copy the contents of the ubuntu (please use the 14.04 or 14.10 release) to your usb -yes just copy
5. Go to your uefi settings and select boot from efi file (again documentation)

( 6. ???

7. Profit)

Also to configure dualbooting with windows just comment and I will update the answer

Answer (score 0):

This question with 0 upvotes and three answers all with 0 upvotes is five years old. You no longer have to install Ubuntu in "Legacy" BIOS mode. UEFI is fully supported with modern Ubuntu 16.04 LTS through to 18.04 LTS beta.